# Trend and seasonality in time series

Tags: r, time-series, trend

This is my data:

```
x <- c(88, 88, 88, 85, 85, 85, 85, 85, 86, 90, 83, 83, 84, 88, 88, 88, 89,
       89, 89, 89, 87, 89, 82, 82, 85, 85, 87, 87, 87, 87, 87, 87, 92, 92,
       84, 84)
```

My purpose here is to check whether `x` has trend or seasonality. What I have done for now is:

```
stlm <- stl(ts(x,frequency = 12), s.window = "periodic")
plot(stlm)
```

[image]

After I get and see graph now I want to measure if trend and seasonality statistically significantly or not. Something like `p-value` in regression analysis.

Does anyone help How can I prove if my data has a trend or seasonality statistically significantly?

Comment: This question is better suited for Cross Validated

Comment: Yes, there are several method in R.